# How to communicate with a gitlab service container

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, clair

I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
stages: 
  - scan

scanning:
  stage: scan
  image: docker:19.03.6
  services:
    - name: arminc/clair-db:latest
    - name: docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
  script:
    - export LOCAL_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS=arminc-clair-db
    - ping -c 4 $LOCAL_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS:5432 #Pinging 'arminc-clair-db:5432' to prove that it IS accessible
    - docker run --interactive --rm --volume "$PWD":/tmp/app -e CI_PROJECT_DIR=/tmp/app -e CLAIR_DB_CONNECTION_STRING="postgresql://postgres:password@${LOCAL_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS}:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable&statement_timeout=60000" -e CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY=vismarkjuarez1994/codigo-initiative -e CI_APPLICATION_TAG=latest registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/klar
```

Everything runs just fine until the last script command, because the host `arminc-clair-db:5432` (which is a service) cannot be resolved.  How do I get my `docker` container to "see" and communicate with the `arminc/clair-db` container?

Below are all the output logs, with the error at the bottom:

```sh
Running with gitlab-runner 13.1.0 (6214287e)
  on docker-auto-scale fa6cab46
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
01:18
Using Docker executor with image docker:19.03.6 ...
Starting service arminc/clair-db:latest ...
Pulling docker image arminc/clair-db:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:032e46f9e42c3f26280ed984de737e5d3d1ca99bb641414b13226c6c62556feb for arminc/clair-db:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:d5d139be840a6ffa04348fc87740e8c095cade6e9cb977785fdba51e5fd7ffec for docker:dind ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
*** WARNING: Service runner-fa6cab46-project-19334692-concurrent-0-f3fcf99fb2cfbb7e-docker-1 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner-fa6cab46-project-19334692-concurrent-0-f3fcf99fb2cfbb7e-docker-1-wait-for-service" timeout
Health check container logs:
Service container logs:
2020-07-13T17:20:21.309966089Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.294373440Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
2020-07-13T17:20:21.310002707Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.300572503Z" level=warning msg="could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found"
2020-07-13T17:20:21.310007147Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.302510800Z" level=warning msg="[!] DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting --tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING [!]"
2020-07-13T17:20:21.310010666Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.307985849Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new containerd process" pid=18
2020-07-13T17:20:21.320081834Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.312042380Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
2020-07-13T17:20:21.320098887Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.312066080Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
2020-07-13T17:20:21.320103371Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.312091196Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
2020-07-13T17:20:21.320107440Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.312100727Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409230132Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.365046801Z" level=info msg="starting containerd" revision=7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429 version=v1.2.13 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409258920Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.380378683Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409263750Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.380477131Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409268507Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.380709522Z" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter" 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409274034Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.380721072Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409277876Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.401607600Z" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs" error="modprobe aufs failed: "ip: can't find device 'aufs'\nmodprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory\n": exit status 1" 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409282127Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.401634659Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409286166Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.401762230Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409290021Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.402131753Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409293511Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.402413697Z" level=info msg="skip loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409296992Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.402424580Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409309649Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.402470351Z" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter" 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409313855Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.402491305Z" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter aufs in metadata plugin" error="modprobe aufs failed: "ip: can't find device 'aufs'\nmodprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory\n": exit status 1" 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.409317643Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.402498473Z" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter zfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter: skip plugin" 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422337155Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.415144189Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.differ.v1.walking"..." type=io.containerd.differ.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422366287Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.415177490Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"..." type=io.containerd.gc.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422370656Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.415220797Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422374289Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.415238800Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.content-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422377575Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.415249745Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422380973Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.415261483Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.images-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422384239Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.415285048Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422387513Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.415296352Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422390735Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.415306615Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422393948Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.415317274Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422397113Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.415539917Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v2.task"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v2 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422400411Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.415661653Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"..." type=io.containerd.monitor.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422403653Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416302031Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422406821Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416331092Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.internal.v1.restart"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422421577Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416366348Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422425309Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416378191Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.content"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422428496Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416388907Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422431715Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416399419Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.events"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422434873Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416410316Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422438168Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416421136Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422441391Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416431148Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422444483Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416441183Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422447730Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416450302Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.internal.v1.opt"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422450979Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416686499Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422454181Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416699740Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422457333Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416710157Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422460460Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.416720291Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422463733Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.417000522Z" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd-debug.sock" 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422466909Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.417067077Z" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock" 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.422470029Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.417076538Z" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.053678s" 
2020-07-13T17:20:21.522992752Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.445278000Z" level=info msg="Setting the storage driver from the $DOCKER_DRIVER environment variable (overlay2)"
2020-07-13T17:20:21.523023868Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.445485273Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
2020-07-13T17:20:21.523028739Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.445497879Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
2020-07-13T17:20:21.523032708Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.445515130Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
2020-07-13T17:20:21.523047388Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.445523771Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
2020-07-13T17:20:21.523051107Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.446951417Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
2020-07-13T17:20:21.523054385Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.446967002Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
2020-07-13T17:20:21.523058180Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.446982738Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
2020-07-13T17:20:21.523061840Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.446991531Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
2020-07-13T17:20:21.523065052Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.499800243Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
2020-07-13T17:20:21.529844429Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.527114868Z" level=warning msg="Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: ip: can't find device 'bridge'\nbridge                167936  1 br_netfilter\nstp                    16384  1 bridge\nllc                    16384  2 bridge,stp\nip: can't find device 'br_netfilter'\nbr_netfilter           24576  0 \nbridge                167936  1 br_netfilter\nmodprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory\n, error: exit status 1"
2020-07-13T17:20:21.680323559Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.642534057Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.18.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
2020-07-13T17:20:21.715621265Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.712210528Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
2020-07-13T17:20:21.741819560Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.740973136Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=48a66213fe graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.12
2020-07-13T17:20:21.743421190Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.741147945Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
2020-07-13T17:20:21.858939063Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.849737479Z" level=info msg="API listen on [::]:2375"
2020-07-13T17:20:21.859149575Z time="2020-07-13T17:20:21.859084136Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
*********
Pulling docker image docker:19.03.6 ...
Using docker image sha256:6512892b576811235f68a6dcd5fbe10b387ac0ba3709aeaf80cd5cfcecb387c7 for docker:19.03.6 ...
Preparing environment
00:03
Running on runner-fa6cab46-project-19334692-concurrent-0 via runner-fa6cab46-srm-1594660737-ea79a1df...
Getting source from Git repository
00:04
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/vismarkjuarez/car-assembly-line/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 71a14f15 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:27
$ docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
$ export LOCAL_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS=arminc-clair-db
$ ping -c 4 $LOCAL_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS:5432
PING arminc-clair-db:5432 (172.17.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.096 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.081 ms
--- arminc-clair-db:5432 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.079/0.085/0.096 ms
$ docker run --interactive --rm --volume "$PWD":/tmp/app -e CI_PROJECT_DIR=/tmp/app -e CLAIR_DB_CONNECTION_STRING="postgresql://postgres:password@${LOCAL_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS}:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable&statement_timeout=60000" -e CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY=[MASKED]/codigo-initiative -e CI_APPLICATION_TAG=latest registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/klar
Unable to find image 'registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/klar:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/klar
c9b1b535fdd9: Pulling fs layer
9d4a5a860853: Pulling fs layer
f02644185e38: Pulling fs layer
01f6d8f93d4f: Pulling fs layer
6756a56563fe: Pulling fs layer
01f6d8f93d4f: Waiting
6756a56563fe: Waiting
9d4a5a860853: Verifying Checksum
9d4a5a860853: Download complete
01f6d8f93d4f: Verifying Checksum
01f6d8f93d4f: Download complete
c9b1b535fdd9: Verifying Checksum
c9b1b535fdd9: Download complete
f02644185e38: Verifying Checksum
f02644185e38: Download complete
6756a56563fe: Verifying Checksum
6756a56563fe: Download complete
c9b1b535fdd9: Pull complete
9d4a5a860853: Pull complete
f02644185e38: Pull complete
01f6d8f93d4f: Pull complete
6756a56563fe: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:229558a024e5a1c6ca5b1ed67bc13f6eeca15d4cd63c278ef6c3efa357630bde
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/klar:latest
[INFO] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:13Z] ▶ GitLab klar analyzer v2.4.8
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:13Z] ▶ Allowlist file with path '/tmp/app/clair-whitelist.yml' does not exist, skipping
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:13Z] ▶ Allowlist file with path '/tmp/app/vulnerability-allowlist.yml' does not exist, skipping
[INFO] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:13Z] ▶ DOCKER_USER and DOCKER_PASSWORD environment variables have not been configured. Defaulting to DOCKER_USER=$CI_REGISTRY_USER and DOCKER_PASSWORD=$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:14Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 1 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:16Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 2 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:18Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 3 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:20Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 4 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:22Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 5 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:24Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 6 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:26Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 7 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:28Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 8 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:30Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 9 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:32Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 10 of 10
[FATA] [klar] [2020-07-13T17:21:34Z] ▶ error while waiting for vulnerabilities database to start. Giving up after 10 retries.: dial tcp: lookup arminc-clair-db on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Is the service really running?

Comment: @abestrad I believe so.  The second script command successfully pings the service `arminc-clair-db:5432`.  I've update the question details to show all of the log output for reference

Comment: the timeout you got is from a different address and port **arminc-clair-db on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host** The service is running  **arminc-clair-db:5432 (172.17.0.3)**

Comment: from the logs, looks like **172.17.0.3* is the real ip that your service got   > Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.18.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address

Comment: `172.17.0.3` is the correct IP I should have been using -- it allowed me access. This is the correct answer.